# Linq with Entity Framework Eager Loading

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, entity, nullreferenceexception

A Customer has many ReservationRequests, a ReservationRequest has only one Customer.

Let's say I retrieve my ReservationRequest like so

```
var c = dataContext.ReservationRequestSet.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == RequestId);
```

I get my ReservationRequest without an issue, but when I do something like this.

```
        if (c != null)
        {
            int id = c.Customers.id;
```

I get a

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 75:             if (c != null)
Line 76:             {
Line 77:                 int id = c.Customers.id;
```

I have very little experience in EF, but this type of thing works in nHibernate without issue, am I missing a setting somewhere in EF?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? The latest supports lazy loading as you would expect it to work, otherwise you have to write a little extra code.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check?

Comment: I suggest to you to change the navigation property of ReservationRequestSet "Customers" in "Customer". It's more redable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly eager load the `Customers` navigation property on `ReservationRequestSet`:

```
var c = dataContext.ReservationRequestSet.Include("Customers")
                                         .FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == RequestId);
```

As of .NET 4, EF performs lazy loading by default but since you are developing a web application I would suggest to turn it off and always use Eager Loading as it might want to attempt to do lazy loading when your object context is closed, therefore cause an exception which is a very typical scenarios in Web and WCF applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework v1, you have to explicitly load children like (to load after you retrieve the Entity):

```
if(!c.CustomersReference.IsLoaded)
    c.CustomersReference.Load();
```

Or (to eager load when you retrieve the Entity):

```
var c = dataContext.ReservationRequestSet
                   .Include("Customers")
                   .FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == RequestId);
```

If you're using Entity Framework v4, you could try using the new Lazy-Loading feature:

```
using(YourContext db = new YourContext())
{
    db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    // query here
}
```

If you go this route, you shouldn't have to worry about explicitly loading navigation properties at all.